# GWT- Need Disclosure Container to open horizontally

Tags: java, gwt, web, widget

I have been looking all day for a simple way to modify the disclosure container to open horizontally rather than vertically, to no avail. I am a beginner Java/ GWT programmer btw.

I have figured out GWT does not directly have a current solution. Additionally, the GWT HorizontalSplitPanel will not suffice. I need a button that the user clicks to close a left side panel of links. When the button is pressed again, it will expand the tab to show the links again.

IOW: i need something similar to what google uses here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!overview

(when you click the expand arrow on the left hand side of the page)

I need to make this into a container in GWT, available to put widgets inside and outside of it. Any advice for this? Do I really need to create a Java animation and everything from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

I need this functionality too. Did you come up with a solution? I was thinking we could extend SplitLayoutPanel and add in the button/widget to expand/collapse.

Comment: Sorry, I never did find a solution. It is still a pending issue for me, but it has been moved from the hot seat for the time being. Not sure about your idea. If a solution is found I would still be very interested in hearing it :)

Comment: Yep - we did hack together something to make it work... we attached an image to the splitter bar and when the image is clicked it opens or closes the splitter pane. It actually works and it looks pretty good (IMHO).